# Placeholder Text color not changing

Tags: html, css

Ok, I've been trying to fix this for a few hours.

I have a placeholder text that doesn't want to change color. At present I have added this CSS

```
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
 }

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
color: red;  
}
```

However, the text is still very light grey.

See the website: http://gravitylab.nz/articles/

help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: on which browser are you testing? for me on FF it's working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/vwy2gqy5/

Comment: Works for me man: http://codepen.io/eGOB/pen/MaWyBV

Comment: Are you sure specific CSS rules are imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code to

> ```
> ::-webkit-input-placeholder {    color: red !important;  }
> ```
>
> :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */    color: red  !important;   }
>
> ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */    color: red !important;   }
>
> :-ms-input-placeholder {   color: red !important;   }

Maybe its getting overridden somewhere... I tried it in the inspector stylesheet of your webpage, and it seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think , You should clear your browser cache fully then try..

```
<html >
    <head >
    <style type="text/css">
        ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: red;
     }

    :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
       color: red;  
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
       color: red;  
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: red;  
    }

    </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
        <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Hello Text" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>


        [![enter image description here][1]][1]



         [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXhbb.png
```